# On Text Input Focus Value Changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('input[type="text"][name="catch_very"]').focus(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'Please Verify That You're Human') {
        $(this).attr('value') = '';
    }
});
```

I'm trying to remove the text 'Please Verify That You're Human' when the user clicks on the select box, does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: make sure you escape that singe quote in "you're"

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$(this).attr('value') = '';
```

to this:

```
$(this).attr('value', '') ;
```

Comment: why exactly does it have to be different from the line before?

Comment: Good question.  Let's break it down.  Calling $(this).attr('value') returns a string.  So in the original code, you are calling a function which returns a string, and then setting that returned string to blank.  However, you are not setting the attribute itself.  To call the function in such a way as to change the attribute, you must pass the new value in as the second parameter to the function.

Comment: I hit Enter on my keyboard too early!  :D :D

Comment: I get what you're saying so I could say var whatever =  $(this).attr('value'). And var what ever would equal  $(this).attr('value')

Comment: I must say that it still seems rather strange?